# STM32F window watchdog with flash erase

Tags: watchdog, stm32f4

I'm using a [STM32F417 microcontroller](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f407-417.html?querycriteria=productId=LN11) and my code runs from flash and I use ST's Window watchdog WWDG.

The problem is that during flash erase the application stalls because, as I said, the code is in the flash and that triggers a watchdog reset!

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

According to RM0090 section 22.3, WWDG can't be disabled once enabled, only reset stops it.

Flash ops are reasonably time consuming and might not fit within window allotted for kicking the dog.

One workaround would be to issue soft reset of the core, then checking on boot whether RCC_CSR bit 28 (software reset flag) is set and then branch off into your DFU of whatever flash manipulation logic. This is assuming you don't normally use soft resets. If you do, then you need to store a flag somewhere, possibly in BKPSRAM.

Other workaround would be to run code from RAM during flash operations

Comment: Another workaround is to set WWDG to the largest possible time-out and then temporarily drop PCLK1 (which clocks the WWDG down-counter) to its lowest value (i.e. biggest prescaler) when erasing flash. Depending on your PCLK1 settings, it can make the WWDG time-out longer by a factor of up to 16. It's also advisable to disable interrupts while erasing (or writing) flash.